# A group of kids get magical powers, including time-freezing

Tags: story-identification, time-travel, magic, young-adult

I remember reading a book back in 3rd or 4th grade ('96/'97) from the school library.  It involved a group of young kids (3 or 4 different kids, pre-teen I think?) who had somehow gotten magical powers.  One of the powers was to Freeze time in a localized area.  Only other little bit I remember was them using the time freeze power to stop a bunch of medieval warriors arrows in midair while they escaped.  Unfortunately, that is all I can remember.

Anyone know the name of the book?

Comment: This description is incredibly vague and [very generic](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/TimeStandsStill). Can you offer any additional detail such as the character's names, their other powers, what they did with these powers. Were they at school? Were they boys or girls? What was the plotline? Was their a villain? Did they embark on some sort of quest>?

Comment: And was it 3-4 young kids, or a group of young kids of 3-4 years of age?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clockstoppers

Comment: I found [The Dark Is Rising](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Dark_Is_Rising_Sequence) which deals with three kids in a medieval setting, who I *think* get access to powers - but they're not the ones who can freeze time.

Comment: Also [The Runelords](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Runelords) which have characters who get "endowments" that boost their metabolisms to the point where time effectively slows down around them.

Comment: I keep thinking of Charmed, which has a series of novels, but the sisters are definitely not kids. :)